# Pesquisa de string com caracter "|"

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex

Preciso realizar uma consulta em um arquivo txt no Python, porém estou com 2 problemas devido a interpretação de caracteres especiais.

Quando insiro `|` ou `\` o resultado acaba sendo substituido: o `|` é interpertado como espaço em branco e `\` é duplicado (`\\`).

```
import re

erro = r"FIM|2|"
linha = 'ahsuasaudsdad '

if re.search(erro, linha):
   print('Não deveria cair aqui')
   print(re.findall(erro, linha))
```

Neste caso eu faço a pesquisa da string `FIM|2|` dentro de um arquivo, porém de qualquer forma ele retorna `true` no `if` sendo que minha intenção é que retorne `true` apenas se a `string` conter `FIM|2|`.

Comment: `|` é um operador de `OU`, tente alterar para `FIM\|2\|`. Ou seja, deste modo `FIM|2|` você está procurando por FIM ou 2 ou nada. Veja [a demo](https://regex101.com/r/eMBgOU/1)

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muito obrigado !

Comment: Eu não tinha aceito ainda porque só posso aceitar 10 min depois dele ter respondido, eu já iria aceitar, obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que o caractere `|` é reservado na expressão regular. O que está acontecendo que é que você está buscando a palavra "FIM" **ou** o número "2" **ou** vazio. O vazio sempre será encontrado.

Para resolver o problema, você precisa escapar o caractere:

```
import re

erro = r"FIM\|2\|"
linha = 'ahsuasaudsdad '

if re.search(erro, linha):
   print('Não deveria cair aqui')
   print(re.findall(erro, linha))
else:
    print('Funcionou :D')
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo !